# ReSharper slow on each startup of Visual Studio 2012

Tags: performance, visual-studio-2012, resharper-7.1

Everytime I start VisualStudio, ReSharper starts to scan around 500 files. When closing the solution without changing anything and starting it again, ReSharper will scan again around 500 files. This is really annoying because there are no changes that needs to be rechecked all the time.
I also cleared caches, switched the folder under which ReSharper stores caches and so on. I did not get any idea what ReSharper is doing all the time.

My system:

- Visual Studio 2012 (Update 4)
- ReSharper 7.1.3

Any ideas?

[dotTrace result](http://www.filedropper.com/dtsn2014-05-14t060109789z)

**Update 1**: Added profiling result

Comment: Profiling can help : menu ReSharper | Help | Profile Visual Studio

Comment: Added the profiling result. I don't have a valid dotTrace license and the trial already ended so I'm unable to check the result myself.